# Different registration form for different roles

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, functions, user-registration

I have customised the worpress registration page by adding new fields using the Cimy User Extra Fields plugin so my site is now fine for allowing users to register as contributors.

I now want to create a different link to allow registrations as subscribers but with different fields displaying on the registration form.

What is the best way to do this?  Another plugin?  PHP functions?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15954/separate-registration-and-login-for-different-roles/15989#15989

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how "Cimy User Extra Fields" works, but you can add fields to the user registration page with:

```
function extra_user_profile_fields_wpse_92164() {
  echo '<label for="extra_field">',_("Extra Field").'</label>';
  echo '<input type="text" name="extra_field" value="" size="25" id="extra_field" />';
}
add_action( 'register_form', 'extra_user_profile_fields_wpse_92164' );
```

To switch subscriber types you could pass in `$_GET` parameters, which is how the default `wp-login.php` forms works. So...

```
function extra_user_profile_fields() {
  if (!isset($_GET['utype'])) return false;
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="register_as" value="'.esc_attr($_GET['utype']).'" />';
  if ('subscriber' == $_GET['utype']) {
    echo '<label for="extra_field_sub">',_("Extra Field Subscriber").'</label>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="extra_field_sub" value="" size="25" id="extra_field_sub" />';
  } else {
    echo '<label for="extra_field">',_("Extra Field").'</label>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="extra_field" value="" size="25" id="extra_field" />';
  }
}
add_action( 'register_form', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
```

Now you can pass data to the form like: `http://example.com/wp-login.php?action=register&utype=subscriber`

You can then save the date pretty much as [demonstrated in the Codex for the `user_register` hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register).

```
 function myplugin_registration_save($user_id) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['extra_field'] ) ) {
      update_user_meta($user_id, 'extra_field', $_POST['extra_field']);
    }
    
    if ( isset( $_POST['extra_field_sub'] ) ) {
      update_user_meta($user_id, 'extra_field_sub', $_POST['extra_field_sub']);
    }
    
    // alter the user Role
    if ('subscriber' == $_POST['register_as'] || 'contributor' == $_POST['register_as']) { 
      wp_update_user(array('ID'=>$user_id,'role'=>$_POST['register_as'])); 
    }
}
add_action('user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save');
```

### Warning

Consider this code 'beta'. I wrote the function to only allow role changes to 'contributor' or 'subscriber' which are low-permission roles, but the function could stand better data validation before being put into service.

Comment: how does that tell it to create the user as a subscriber rather than the default setting of contributor?

Comment: LOl... you are right. You could parse the extra fields and infer that but I should have included a hidden field. I'll edit things.

Comment: also...what would then happen if the http://example.com/wp-login.php?action=register page was accessed without adding one of the &utype=subscriber or http://example.com/wp-login.php?action=register&utype=contributor? Which fields would show? Neither? That would be a problem...

Comment: On my system, the default form appears and the user is registered as a subscriber. "Cimy" may have changed that for you.

Comment: yeah I follow that, that's great. How would validation checks work/affect the form submission?

Comment: I'm worried about that too. That hook runs at the end of the user registration process. WordPress validation should occur before that code executes, but won't effect the new fields. I wrote the function to only allow "role" changes to 'contributor' or 'subscriber' but that is minimal. You should think through the validation carefully.

Comment: Do the fields need to be created in the user profile section too?  Otherwise where are they saved to?