# wordpress separate registration for different roles

Tags: php, user-roles, user-registration

When a user click on a link to register it should assign them a different role, and not the default role. I've tried this link but it doesnt seem to work. I've placed it in the functions.php.

[Separate registration and login for different roles](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15954/separate-registration-and-login-for-different-roles)

I dont need a plugin just the php code.

For example if the user click on this link it should give them the seller role automatically
http://example.com/wp-login.php?action=register&role=seller
If the user click on this link http://example.com/wp-login.php?action=register
it should give them the default role.

Thanks

Comment: Have you created your hidden field in your form?

Comment: yes I have. Check the link. I've did the same thing (
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15954/separate-registration-and-login-for-different-roles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first you the `register_form` action hook is applied to the default WP registration form, so keep this in mind if you don't use that.

Secondly, the `add_action` is calling an unknown function. So most likely this is why it's not working.

So here's the corrected code. With added validation with error messages.

```
//create a hidden field for role
add_action('register_form','wpse_add_hidden_role_field');
  function wpse_add_hidden_role_field(){
    if ( isset( $_GET[ 'role' ] ) ){
      echo '<input id="user_role" type="hidden" tabindex="20" size="25" value="' . $_GET[ 'role' ] . '" name="role"/>';
  }
}


//validate we have permitted roles if not, don't allow subscription
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'wpse_role_check' );
function wpse_role_check( $errors ){

  if( isset( $_POST[ 'role' ] ) ) {

    //only allow registration if roles are in this array.
    $permitted_roles = array(
        'buyer',
        'seller',
    );

    if( ! in_array( $_POST[ 'role' ], $permitted_roles ) ){

        $errors->add( 'role_not_allowed', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: This registration is not allowed.', 'my_textdomain' ) );

    }

  }

  // Else disallow public registration (i.e. no role query string found )
  // If you don't take this into account, anyone can register as subscribers
  else {

    $errors->add( 'public_not_allowed', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Public registration is not allowed.', 'my_textdomain' ) );

  }

  return $errors;

}

//update user profile that have passed registration validation
add_action('user_register', 'wpse_update_role');
function wpse_update_role( $user_id ) {
  if ( isset( $_POST[ 'role' ] ) ){
    $userdata = array();
    $userdata[ 'ID' ] = $user_id;
    $userdata[ 'role' ] = $_POST[ 'role' ];

    wp_update_user( $userdata );

  }
}
```

Comment: do I have to add anything in the wp-login.php page? like do_action( 'register_form' );

Comment: no, this should work as is.  You should _not_ edit core files. Unless you are using a custom form registration, then yes, you will need to add a custom hook into your form, like `custom_form_hook` and hook there

Comment: Glad you got it working. Cheers! Mark it as solve so we can keep this site tidy :)

Comment: Also if the users use this link http://example.com/wp-login.php?action=register can they go straight to subscriber role? Because at the moment if the user use that link it says public registration is not allowed

Comment: Yes, they can, remove the `else` statement in `wpse_role_check` and it should work

Comment: don't forget to mark it as solved (green check mark) if it solved your issue :)

Comment: Hi, I've noticed when I enabled email confirmation, the role doesn't change to the seller role. 
If I disabled it then it works. Im using cimy user extra fields plugin for email confirmation

Comment: This would be related to your plugin. It looks like the plugin is modifying the registration by intercepting the data. We check to see if `$_POST` is set before updating the user profile, but if your plugin gets in the middle and stores `$_POST` data temporarily waiting for confirmation to be completed before updating the profile, then `$_POST` won't be set anymore. So you need to look at maybe some kind of hooks that your plugin offers, if any, so you could retrieve the value for your role.